# How can I stop a simple image scroller from scrolling too far with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the jQuery I'm using to scroll through a horizontal list of small images with left and right buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".left").click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".mover").animate({marginLeft: '+=60px'}, 0);
});

$(".right").click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".mover").animate({ marginLeft: '-=60px' }, 0);
});
});
```

Right now there is no limit to how far you can make the list scroll. Is there a simple way to limit this?

Comment: Check if the marginLeft is larger or smaller that a certain number, for your right and left end respectively?

Comment: http://css-plus.com/2010/09/create-your-own-jquery-image-slider/  Take a look at the example in this tutorial. a little addition, subtraction and multiplication and you have it.